# Why is this program being unexpectedly stopped?

Tags: android

Why isn't this code working? I've been stuck on this for 2 days.

```
public  class SongsActivity extends Activity{

        DemoView demoview ;
        FinalView finalview;
        ViewFlipper c ;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            demoview = new DemoView(this);
            finalview = new FinalView(this);
               // adding view to the viewflipper
            c.addView(demoview,0);
            c.addView(finalview, 1);
                ///initializing the fliiper
            c=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);

            c.setAutoStart(true);
            c.setFlipInterval(500);
            c.startFlipping();

        }
```

Comment: I think Booyakka identified the problem: just move the `addView` calls so that then come after you have assigned a value to `c`. In general, though, you should post the logcat output showing whatever exception is causing your program to fail.

Comment: @tedhopp i am new to this site can you suggest me how i upload the my file on this site of teh logcat

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, you can open the logcat view, highlight the relevant rows, and copy/paste into your message here. If you're extracting logcat with adb, save to a text file and copy/paste from that. Format it as code so that it doesn't line wrap.

Comment: @tedhopp mylogcat file is as foloow

Comment: tedhopp 03-19 03:32:47.402: W/dalvikvm(403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-19 03:32:47.424: E/AndroidRuntime(403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 03:32:47.424: E/AndroidRuntime(403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtablayout/com.example.androidtablayout.SongsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 03:32:47.424: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-19 03:32:47.424: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
03-19 03:32:47.424: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)03-19 03:32:47.424: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:

Comment: Look down the list for the last "Caused by..." and paste from there to the end.

Comment: @tedHopp  i got the my answer. thanks for teh help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `findViewById` before setting the view of your `Activity` using `setContentView`.

Although Booyakka's answer is partially correct, you're not setting the content view with anything that contains a `ViewFlipper` with the resId `R.id.viewFlipper1`.

As a result, the line...

```
c=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
```

Will set c to null even if you've initialized it as Booyakka's suggestion.

Why are you not using `setContentView(...)` with a layout xml? The fact you are trying to find a view with the resId `R.id.viewFlipper1` suggests you've created the layout xml but you're not inflating it and that's part of the cause of your problem.

**EDIT**: Inflating a layout is taking the contents of an XML layout file and instantiating the objects it describes. Do this with `setContentView(<layout-resource-id>)` BEFORE attempting to use `findViewById`

Try changing your `onCreate()` method as below using the name of the layout file you created.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the main.xml file using the following...
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Move the findViewById(...) call to here...
    c=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);

    demoview = new DemoView(this);
    finalview = new FinalView(this);

    c.addView(demoview,0);
    c.addView(finalview, 1);

    c.setAutoStart(true);
    c.setFlipInterval(500);
    c.startFlipping();
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the inflating ?

Comment: See the EDIT to the end of my answer above.

Comment: i have two problem 
one is that i am setting the resolution of the avd for my project but it is not showing properly it is showing blur copy . 
Second is i want to create 3d image which should roatate how should i create that can nay one help.or can give any useful link .

Answer (score 2):

you are adding view before initialising.

when you call c.addView(demoview, 0);  c is null because it has not been initialised. 
so initialise c with ViewFlipper and add the views after.

Comment: Then you made another mistake. Post the new error log as a comment.

Comment: lol. If you think http://C:\Documents and Settings\dtr\log.txt is a valid link, you have bigger issues than writing vaild android code.

Comment: @adelphus io know that i am trying that my computer file can uplode on this or not i just searching that but i had just copy and past from url that is my mistake buddy , i know that

Comment: @Ashishsingh that's ok - just thought it was funny. You can (and should) delete your comment if it's not relevant.